# BlackBerry - Disable show default menu on screen open

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, menu, blackberry-storm

I have labels and fields in my application screen. When i launch to a particular screen which has many labels and editfields and buttons. The problem is, when i launch a particular screen, default menu is popping up with "Show Keyboard", "Switch Applicaiton" and "Full menu" automatically when launching a particular screen. I don't want to get this menu when launching a screen. How do i ignore showing it? How to do that. Please advice.
Note: Eventhough there is no controls in the same screen, Menu is still popping up this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using a `ButtonField` to launch the new screen, make sure you add the `ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK` style to its constructor so that the click event is not passed on down to the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. That's been annoying me for quite a while :)